# How to remove both type newlines using only bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, newlines

The variable v has \n and, hm, another type newline??

```
v='ab\n cd
 ef
'
printf '%b' "$v"
ab
 cd
 ef
printf '%s' "$v"
ab\n cd
 ef
printf '%s' "$v" | xxd
00000000: 6162 5c6e 2063 640a 2065 660a            ab\n cd. ef.
printf '%b' "$v" | xxd
00000000: 6162 0a20 6364 0a20 6566 0a              ab. cd. ef.
```

printf '%b' shows both newlines as the ASCII 10 character.

My function removes both type newlines but it uses different processes for each type.

```
remove() {
  local str="$1" chr='\\n\\t\\r' idx
  for (( idx=0; idx<${#chr}; idx+=$((${#chr} / 3)) )); do   
    str="${str//${chr:${idx}:3}}"
  done
  str=${str//[$'\n\t\r']}
  printf "${str}"
}
```

Is there a better way to handle both with a single process using only Bash?

I'm using GNU bash 4.4.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't really two types of newlines; `\n` is just a character sequence until you pass it to `printf '%b'` or some other command such as `echo -e` that interprets it as a backslash escape sequence.

So you could use `printf '%b'` to convert any `\n` sequences to newlines, then remove all the newlines using parameter substitution and a bash [C-string](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings):

```
v='ab\n cd                     
 ef
'
printf -v w '%b' "$v"; printf '%s\n' "${w//$'\n'}"
ab cd ef
```

Comment: Using printf is simpler and avoids my duplicate process, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use echo.
Whithout -e and ", echo see \n as string and you can remove it using parameter substitution.

```
echo ${v//\\n}
```

Comment: This is a simpler approach and does remove both reps of newline but I've been stumped trying to put \\n in a variable such that it will still remove both reps of newline. Is there a way to make a variable of \\n work?

Comment: Not sure I understand well. If you have var='test\\ntry', you can catch \\n like that : echo ${var//\\\\n}

Comment: I was mistaken. If I don't include ${v//\\n} in double quotes then echo replaces the actual newline with a space. If in double quotes then echo does not replace the actual newline in $v, only the newline symbol \n. I am looking for v='ab\n cd
 ef' with both representations of newline and rep='\\n' such that "${v//${rep}} will remove both representations of newline.

Comment: Unfortunately this note feature eats the pasted in newline but the variable in the question above shows both reps of newline being entered into v.